# ¿Cómo empaquetar los Frames de forma ordenada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

***¡Hola Comunidad!***

Deseo distribuir tres (3) widgets de tipo `Frame` para una GUI. Cada uno de ellos contendrá en su interior otros widgets, por ejemplo, los del tipo `Label`, que muestran un determinado texto.

**La siguiente imagen muestra el como debería quedar:**

[image: Distribución de los Frame(s)]

*"Los Frames tienen esa nomenclatura de color para representar, aproximadamente, las dimensiones que debe tener cada uno. La ventana se muestra en tamaño maximizado."*

Implementé dos (2) formas distintas de programar el código que lograse esa estructura de la GUI. En la primera, los "Frames" fueron empaquetados por el método `grid()`, mientras que en la segunda, por el método `pack()`. En ninguna, se muestra el resultado esperado.

**Código 1:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        fm1 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='red')
        fm1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        fm2 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='blue')
        fm2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew'),

        fm3 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='green')
        fm3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        tk.Label(fm1, text='Frame 1').pack()
        tk.Label(fm2, text='Frame 2').pack()
        tk.Label(fm3, text='Frame 3').pack()

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo1 = App()
    ejemplo1.mainloop()
```

**Código 2:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        fm1 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='red')
        fm1.pack(fill='x')

        fm2 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='blue')
        fm2.pack(fill='y', expand=True, anchor='nw')

        fm3 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='green')
        fm3.pack(fill='y', expand=True, anchor='ne')

        tk.Label(fm1, text='Frame 1').pack()
        tk.Label(fm2, text='Frame 2').pack()
        tk.Label(fm3, text='Frame 3').pack()

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo2 = App()
    ejemplo2.mainloop()
```

***¡Gracias por sus comentarios y sugerencias!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar `grid` es posiblemente una buena opción en éste caso, lo que tienes que tener en cuenta es:

- Usar `rowconfigure` y `columnconfigure` para asignar un peso proporcional a cada fila y columna. A simple vista parece que la segunda fila es unas 4 veces la primera y que la primera columna es el doble de ancha que la segunda.
- Usa el argumento `uniform` de los métodos anteriores para crear grupos de columnas o filas. Dentro de un mismo grupo, el espacio se reparte siempre de forma uniforme a sus pesos, sin importar el contenido interno.

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1)
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="rows_g1")
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=5, uniform="rows_g1")
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3,  uniform="cols_g1")
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1,  uniform="cols_g1")

        fm1 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='red')
        fm1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')

        fm2 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='blue')
        fm2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew'),

        fm3 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='green')
        fm3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        tk.Label(
            fm1, text='FRAME 1',  bg="red",  fg="white", font=("Courier", 20)
            ).pack(expand=True)
        tk.Label(
            fm2, text='FRAME 2',  bg="blue",  fg="white", font=("Courier", 20), 
            ).pack(expand=True)
        tk.Label(
            fm3, text='FRAME 3', bg="green",  fg="white", font=("Courier", 20)
            ).pack(expand=True)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo1 = App()
    ejemplo1.mainloop()
```

Los pesos solo pueden ser enteros, debes jugar con las proporciones para obtener el resultado más ajustado al deseado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la ventana se re-escala, los frames también lo harán, pero siempre mantendráan las proporciones, en éste caso 1:5 las filas y 3:1 las columnas. Si se desea se puede forzar un tamaño mínimo también.

### NOTA

La línea:

```
self.root.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1)
```

es usada para maximizar la ventana, no obstante no hay una forma que sea totalmente universal entre sistemas operativos y gestores de ventanas.

Como @gv-pro comenta, en Windows falla, existen otraas posibilidades, por ejemplo, en Windows debe funcionar:

```
self.root.state('zoomed')
```

Obtener el alto y ancho máximo de la ventana y asignarlos mediante el método `geometry` es otra opción bastante universal:

```
ancho = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
alto = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
self.root.geometry(f"{x}x{y}+0+0")
```

aunque puede fallar en determinados SO, generalmente por retornar dimensiones incorrectas o porque la posición 0 no se setea de forma adecuada. En el caso de trabajar sin pantallas físicas también puede ser un problema.

Otra opción es:

```
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
```

que tampoco funciona en Windows.

Comment: ¡Hola FJSevilla! Al ejecutar el código me aparece un error en la línea donde se encuentra: self.root.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1).

El error que muestra la intérprete es:
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"

Estoy desarrollando la app bajo el sistema operativo Windows 10.

Comment: Esa línea solo pretende maximizar la ventana, no afecta al resto. No hay una forma universal de forzar el maximizado que funcione en todos los SO y gestores de ventanas, en Windows, si mal no recuerdo puedes cambiarla por `self.root.state('zoomed')`

Comment: Entendido. Modifiqué un poco el código, pues he estado implementado los métodos self.root.winfo_screenwidth() y self.root.winfo_screenheight() para luego pasarlos como argumentos del método self.root.geometry() para dimensionar la ventana y ha funcionado perfectamente. Gracias por las respuestas!

Comment: Efectivamente es otra posibilidad bastante universal, pero también falla en determinados gestores de ventanas...